# QGIS crashes when trying to return layer from processing toolbox console

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing

The following script is intended to take a polygon layer and extract the features having a particular value ('natural') in a given field ('landuse') and return the selection.

Everything seems to work fine until the final line where the results are returned. QGIS crashes.

If i set Output to "none", the script runs fine. And I check the resulting layer with vlayer.isValid and it always returns true.

Moreover, if instead of 'OUTPUT': 'memory:', i set 'OUTPUT': 'results.shp',  the resulting layer, written on disk, is good.

I don't know what's causing all the trouble. To recreate it you can pick any polygon layer (be it geopackage or shapefile) that has a selection attribute and set the corresponding values under 'FIELD' and 'VALUE'.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                   QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                   QgsProcessingException,
                   QgsProcessingOutputNumber,
                   QgsProcessingParameterDistance,
                   QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                 QgsProcessingParameterVectorDestination,
                QgsProcessingParameterRasterDestination,
                QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink ,
                QgsProcessingOutputVectorLayer,
                QgsVectorLayer
                   )
import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):   
def tr(self, string):
    return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

def createInstance(self):      
    return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

def name(self):    
    return 'bufferrasterextend'

def displayName(self):
    return self.tr('Buffer and export to raster (extend)')

def group(self):      
    return self.tr('Example scripts')

def groupId(self):      
    return 'examplescripts'

def shortHelpString(self):
    return self.tr('Example algorithm short description')

def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):         
    self.addParameter(
        QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
            'OUTPUT',
            self.tr("Output layer"),
            QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry
        )
    )

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):        
    extract_natural = processing.run("native:extractbyattribute", {
        'FIELD': 'landuse', 
        'INPUT': 'path_to_layer/vienna_landuse.gpkg|layername=vienna_landuse',                     
        'OPERATOR': 0, 
        'OUTPUT': 'memory:', 
        'VALUE': 'natural'
    })            

    vlayer = extract_natural['OUTPUT']        

    if vlayer.isValid():
        feedback.setProgressText("Layer ok")
    else:
        feedback.setProgressText("Layer is wrong!")

    return {
        #'OUTPUT': None # works fine
        'OUTPUT': vlayer # qgis crashes
    }
```

Comment: @germán carrillo

Comment: I myself am facing this same issue (and now I see you tagged me!). Have a look at this algorithm in the [QGIS docs](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#the-alg-decorator). It can set a QGIS layer as output. The only difference I can see is that it uses decorators.